# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Enhanced Health Not Reporting Data on Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS ElasticBeanstalk is not showing any requests nor latency data for my environments:

[image: Environment enhanced health dashboard]

I've configured the environment as the documentation says, that is, enabling the **Enhanced health reporting** and the CloudWatch log streaming:

[image: Environment enhanced health configuration]

I SSH'ed into my instances to confirm that the CloudWatch Agent is running:

`[ec2-user@ip-10-0-103-254 ~]$ sudo service awslogs status
awslogs (pid  4955) is running...`

Here is the version of the Agent:

`[ec2-user@ip-10-0-103-254 ~]$ sudo yum info awslogs
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
Name        : awslogs
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 1.1.2
Release     : 1.10.amzn1
Size        : 11 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : Scripts for CloudWatch Logs Daemon
URL         : http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch
License     : Amazon Software License
Description : Scripts to run Amazon CloudWatch Logs as a daemon.`

The **/var/log/awslogs.log** file is showing this:

`2018-07-19 03:59:12,011 - cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3188 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/httpd/error_log*'.
2018-07-19 03:59:12,011 - cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3188 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/httpd/access_log*'.
2018-07-19 03:59:12,012 - cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3188 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/nginx/error.log*'.
2018-07-19 03:59:12,012 - cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3188 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/nginx/access.log*'.`

I'm using Apache, so I don't worry for the Nginx files not being found. The thing is, the files **[...]/httpd/error_log** and **access_log** *DO* exist on that directory. However, they are always empty:

[image: Empty log group for environment]

Since I'm using Tomcat 7 with Apache, I thought that adding the **/var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access.txt** log to the CloudWatch streaming might allow the data to appear. This is the log I added to the stream:

`` [/var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.txt]
   log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.txt"]]}`
   log_stream_name = {instance_id}
   file = /var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log* ``

I then restarted the Agent, but it didn't work either. The logs did appear on CloudWatch, but data wasn't reported to ElasticBeanstalk.

Any thoughts on somewhere else to look? I'm kind of lost now.

**EDIT**

Here is the environment health dashboard from the EB CLI for a production workload of one of our services (using `eb health --refresh`):

[image: EB CLI health dashboard for production workload]

Comment: The numbers that you see are over the last 10 seconds. [More information here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-metrics.html). To validate the numbers look right, I recommend you write a script that generates traffic for your application over a period of 30s and notice how that affects the numbers in the health dashboard. This could have been the source of confusion.

Comment: As an aside, you do not *need* to enable CloudWatch log streaming -- the metrics you see missing will be reported regardless.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Thing is we're running production loads with some thousands of requests per minute on ElasticBeanstalk, but still no data- apart from the CPU- is being reported.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. Can you try `eb health --refresh` through the EBCLI? Can you verify your experience is similar through the EBCLI?

Comment: I edited the question and added the eb health dashboard from the EB CLI, it shows the same behavior.

Comment: Hey @david-ojeda, I am having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @ViniciusTavares. My ElasticBeanstalk dashboard still shows no metrics...

Comment: I expierience the issue with missing metrics too.